# Unhandled Server Error!!! unknown attribute 'image' for Property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, base64, paperclip

I am struggling to resolved this problem. I use `React Js` as front-end and and `Ruby on Rails` for back-end. I pass some value from `React` side to `Ruby on Rails` to be processed. The value is passed through API with `cycle.js`. Basically, what I am doing is **1) Convert image to Base64,** **2) Use `Paperlip` to attach image for `Property`,** **3) Store the Base64 string in the server.**
 The error is:

```
 Unhandled Server Error!!!
 unknown attribute 'image' for Property.
```

This is the code for back-end:

**property.rb**

```
 class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
 include PropertySharedMethods
 has_many :property_images, as: :imageable
```

**property_image.rb**

```
 class PropertyImage < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

 has_attached_file :image
 # Validate content type
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage/
```

So, property_image is polymorphic. The image upload will be uploaded to AWS. For the front-end, the API request is successful, but I do not know whats wrong with my back-end code that creates this error.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You have to call `#image` on `PropertyImage` instance, not on `Property` one(this is the source of the error).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you really need `polymorphic` there.

Comment: I use `polymorphic` because the `property` function is to save data of the property and link it with `property_image` using `imageable_id`. The `property_image` is to save the images or Base64 string.

Comment: Check your controller for permitted params, you may have forgot to add image to the list of the permitted params e.g.: `params.require(:property_image).permit(:image)`

Comment: @teckden, you are correct. It is about permitting the param `image`. Thanks!!!

Comment: @ArifMustaffa Glad to help :) I have moved my comment to an answer, please accept it if it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to check your controller for permitted params, you may have forgot to add image to the list of the permitted params e.g.: `params.require(:property_image).permit(:image)`